# What are some benefits and pitfalls of ODT (Observation Driven Testing)?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, tdd, invariants

We just came upon the [whitepaper](http://www.agitar.com/pdf/Paper-Agitar-ODT-TDD.pdf) *"Observation Driven Testing: Yes, the code is doing what you want. By the way, what else is it doing?"*, and were intrigued.

However, Google doesn't seem to reveal much about how it works in practice ([1](http://www.google.com/search?q=odt+observation+driven+testing), [2](http://www.google.com/?q=observation+driven+testing+review)). Everything out there seems to be from a vendor, [Agitar](http://www.agitar.com/).

Has anyone implemented ODT as a complementary process to TDD and CI?

If so, please share some of the **benefits** and **pitfalls** you've encountered with it... we'd love to benefit from your wisdom.

Comment: Might be missing something obvious here - w.r.t. the example in the whitepaper, wouldn't reviewing the tests once (before you hit the keyboard) be a faster way of catching that particular defect. The issue was in translating the req. text into automated tests.. TDD can't help you if you get your specs wrong. The idea seems to be closer to finding *Invariants* in your code + then verifying that the invariant holds... in practice IMHO good idea.. not sure if it will take root in most teams.

Comment: That said... I just looked at the 4th flash demo on their site. I'm a little less skeptical :) The whitepaper doesn't do it justice. The tool suggests **potential invariants**, which is interesting. If it was in the .net world, I'd definitely give this a whirl... +1 for posting this.

Comment: Probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CameronSkinner I don't even know what that is, but it sounds like an attempt to kill the value of StackOverflow.com via unnecessary fragmentation of content and community

Comment: @ms-tg: Well, if you don't know what it is then I'm not sure why you're claiming that it's an attempt to kill the value of StackOverflow. In fact, it's run by the same people and is a site for programming discussions. From the FAQ: "Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development". I suggest you take a look at it and read the FAQ before making bizarre claims.

Comment: I think it works on SO because the answer winds up being about what a specific tool does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observation-Driven Testing is more or less Agitar's term for using their product. I evaluated Agitar's product several years ago. It doesn't replace normal unit testing but works alongside it. Although there is a process to using it, as there is to everything, I wouldn't consider it a process on the level of TDD or CI or CD -- it's as much like using a static analysis tool as it is like testing. Nonetheless it is very powerful and interesting.

Its core functionality is invariant detection, which Agitar calls agitation. It finds all of the methods in your code and executes each with an automatically determined set of parameter values. It is sophisticated in how it chooses parameter values: it does relatively obvious things like using MIN_VALUE, -1, 0, 1 and MAX_VALUE for ints, but it is also able to watch existing test code run and harvest interesting values to use when agitating. It has explicit support for objects with external dependencies like JDBC Connections.

After running all of a class's methods with the chosen parameter values, Agitar makes observations (candidate invariants) about parameter values, method return values and values of fields. It presents them to the user, who can either promote them to invariants, which will be tested for in future agitation runs, or change the code so the observation becomes impossible. For example, Agitar might observe that calling a method with one parameter being null causes the method to throw `NullPointerException`. Changing the code to handle the null will eliminate that observation in future runs.

Agitar can generate JUnit tests from its observations. I don't know of any advantages that offers over just maintaining the invariants in Agitar's tool.

I didn't buy Agitar's product, but I still have great respect for what I saw and would consider it again in the right environment (Java, strong business need for bulletproof code). It found bugs in code that I had developed with TDD and which had nearly 100% line and branch coverage. Even better, watching it work improved how I think about unit tests!

Regarding pitfalls: it is specific to Java, proprietary and expensive. Also, because it is such a thorough tool and its observations are coupled to implementation details, it would take a lot of effort to maintain Agitar's view of a program that was being actively developed (more than maintaining the acceptance/integration/unit test suite).

This is the best quick introduction to agitation that I found: http://www.agitar.com/downloads/demos/agi_demo/agiDemo.html. There is interesting reading on a predecessor and related systems here: http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon/pubs/. Also, [ScalaCheck](http://scalacheck.org/) appears to implement a similar although much simpler process.

Comment: Agitar wrote a research article too: [From Daikon to Agitator: Lessons and Challenges in Building a Commercial Tool for Developer Testing](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.901.1039%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ved=2ahUKEwj4xLmT4qLxAhWWWc0KHWCyAqsQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3ja7_M8iWmcHAM9VnVzbAJ&cshid=1624074027445).

Comment: Good callout, but that link doesn't work for me right now so here's a different link to the same article: https://www.albertosavoia.com/uploads/1/4/0/9/14099067/fromdaikontoagitator.pdf